# How VPN server knows the ip packet result belongs to which client?

Tags: node.js, networking, ip, vpn

I have created my own vpn server in node js using my very own protocol ( not using open Vpn or wiregaurd or any other protocol).

It works pretty good for one client connected. But when more clients connect to vpn it gets confusing.

When clients send ip packets to server my vpn server replaces ip packets source ip address with vpn server's own public ip address in order to hide clients actual ip address and to receive results from server and forward them to client.

The problem is whencmultiple clients connect to vpn server in time of receiving result ip packets from destination servers, since all destination ip addresses are the same ( vpn server's public ip address) the vpn server doesn't now that to which client the result packets should be forwarded.

I have tried assigning each client a virtual ip address to emphesize them but since the router of vpn server's network doesn't know about virtual ip addresses the result ip packets won't be routed to vpn server at all to be forwarded to client then.

I've been working on this for weeks but couldn't do any progress. How can I fix this issue?

I've tried assigning virtual ip addresses to clients and I know that port forwarding won't work for me.